# Can I make Visual Studio's code completion window more like Eclipse (Java)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, code-completion

Is it possible to make Visual Studio 2010's code completion window more like that of Eclipse (Java)?

In particular, I'd love the code completion window to give me a variable's type, and a method's return type and expected parameters, without needing to hover the highlight over that particular variable/method.  Here's Eclipse's:

[image]

VS's code completion's little icons that indicate if something is a property, method etc are useful, but they just aren't enough.

Comment: Screenshots? I've never used Eclipse, but I'm having trouble imagining how the Intellisense could show all of that information for each item without taking up the entire screen.

Comment: Certainly.  Sorry, I was having problems uploading an image, but i got it to work finally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to do this. Visual Studio offers only very limited options related to customizing its Intellisense display.

You'll have to turn to third-party solutions or add-ins, or settle down to write your own using one of the existing options as a guide. Here are a few that can be found around the web:

- [Visual Studio Intellisense Presenter](http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntelliSense%20Presenter) (looks like it might be very close to what you're looking for)
- [CSharpIntellisensePresenter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c3eaa4fc-f2de-43ad-92ee-f0f257b79005)
- [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp) (commercial software with 30-day free trial)

Comment: Thanks, I figured a third-party addin was probably the answer, thanks for recommending some.  I've been using Eclipse for too long, switching to VS has proved a bit of a challenge in places!

Comment: @Matt: I enjoyed the question, actually (I'd have upvoted if I wasn't long out of votes). I've *only* used Visual Studio (and similar) IDEs, so I had never even thought of the Intellisense popup looking any different. (See, I don't even know what else to call it but "Intellisense".) I still think it looks messy in Eclipse compared to VS 2010, but it's still an interesting idea to show the types and all the overloads separately.