# Create Intellisense Addin For Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Can anyone point me to some articles that detail how to create custom intellisense support in Visual Studio? I want to create an intellisense that will pull data from a different data source.

Comment: Check this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690233/can-i-make-visual-studios-code-completion-window-more-like-eclipse-java You can start with this...